# Moving arrays between procedures and class objects

Tags: arrays, vba, class

I'm having trouble moving arrays between class objects. The idea is to add certain data to a class object, change some parameters within a 2-dimensional array and return that array to the main procedure. I have tried everything, from a public array to even putting the array into a public dictionary but I cannot get it out of the class.

```
Sub ClassArray()

Dim Arr() As Variant
ReDim Arr(1 To 2) As Variant
Arr(1) = "A"
Arr(2) = "B"

Set Class = New ClassObject
Class.Add Arr

Debug.Print Class.Count
Range("A1:C3") = Class.Matrix

End Sub
```

My Class Object:

```
Private ClassMatrix(1 To 1, 1 To 1) As Variant
Private Counter As Long
'------
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'Appaerently putting the ReDim statement here doesn't do anything
End Sub
'------
Public Sub Add(ByVal Arr As Variant)

x = 3
y = 3

Dim ClassMatrix() As Variant
ReDim ClassMatrix(1 To y, 1 To x)

If Arr(1) = "A" Then
    ClassMatrix(1, 1) = 1
End If

If Arr(2) = "B" Then
    ClassMatrix(3, 3) = 1
End If

End Sub
'------
Property Get Count() As Long
    For x = 1 To 3
        For y = 1 To 3
            If ClassMatrix(y, x) = 1 Then Counter = Counter + 1
        Next y
    Next x
    Count = Counter
End Property
'------
Property Get Matrix() As Variant
    Matrix = ClassMatrix
End Property
```

What has also given me a lot of trouble with class objects is that the debugger never highlights the line that's causing the issue? I find it makes debugging them rather hard compared to your regular procedure.

Comment: Your Add method is working upon a local array, not the one defined at the class level.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer Brain? I have declared the UserMatrix array as private to be used within the class?

Comment: "I cannot get it out of the class" - exactly what happens when your code runs?

Comment: `Dim ClassMatrix() As Variant` in `Add` creates a local array which "hides" the global one.

Comment: For your debuggin issues try Tools.Options.General and check the 'Break on All Errors' radio button.  If you don't do this then you can't get errors in classes reported.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the arraylist object and build yourself an arraylist of arraylists.

Comment: I'm at a loss here as to why I couldn't get it working. Spend literally hours on figuring it out. I got the concept going, will post the code below. @ freeflow, this is a really big help, thank you so much. @Mathieu, I think I got some things confused as to dimensioning arrays in public, private, then redimming them somewhere else. With the code below I could use the Class_Initialize to set the size once for every class created.

Comment: @Tim, if you have a dictionary with keys, would it be possible to create class objects using those keys as the class (name) variable? Because Set dict.Keys()(0) = New ClassObject doesn't allow me to later dict.Keys()(0).Add something to that class.

Comment: You can't use an object as a Key in a dictionary, but you can use it as a Value.

Answer (score 1):

With some help I got the following code working for anyone looking for a similar solution:

```
Option Explicit
Public dict As Dictionary
'------
Sub ClassArray()

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict("key1") = "item1"
dict("key2") = "item2"
dict("key3") = "item3"
Debug.Print "dict.Count", dict.Count 'will return 3

Dim Arr() As Variant
ReDim Arr(1 To 2) As Variant

Dim Class As Object
Set Class = New ClassObject

Arr(1) = "A"
Class.Add Arr
Arr(2) = "B"
Class.Add Arr

Debug.Print "Class.Count", Class.Count 'will return 2
Range("A1:C3") = Class.Matrix

End Sub
```

Class Object:

```
Option Explicit
Private ClassMatrix() As Variant
Private Counter As Long
'------
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

Dim x, y
x = dict.Count
y = dict.Count

ReDim ClassMatrix(1 To y, 1 To x)

Debug.Print "ClassMatrix dimensions", UBound(ClassMatrix, 1), UBound(ClassMatrix, 2) 'will return 3, 3

End Sub
'------
Public Sub Add(ByVal Arr As Variant)

If Arr(1) = "A" Then
    ClassMatrix(1, 1) = 1
End If

If Arr(2) = "B" Then
    ClassMatrix(3, 3) = 1
End If

End Sub
'------
Property Get Count() As Long

Dim x, y
For x = 1 To 3
    For y = 1 To 3
        If ClassMatrix(y, x) = 1 Then Counter = Counter + 1
    Next y
Next x
Count = Counter

End Property
'------
Property Get Matrix() As Variant

    Matrix = ClassMatrix

End Property
```